# Disable Flash in Safari for all but YouTube

Tags: safari, adobe-flash

I dislike Flash intensely (from a security standpoint, plus constantly nagging me to install security updates) and would love to uninstall it in its entirety but unfortunately YouTube requires it. Is there an easy way to disable flash in Safari 6.0.2 for all sites except *.YouTube.com ?

I'm only concerned about Safari, not so much Firefox and Chrome which I only use on rare occasions.

Running Mac OS X 10.8.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give ["Click to Flash"](http://clicktoflash.com/) a try. I believe that it does pretty much everything you are asking for.

This plugin disables flash in Safari by default, but to load some flash content all you have to do is click on the "Flash" button in a video and the video will load and play as usual. You can even whitelist sites in ["Click to Flash"](http://clicktoflash.com/) so you won't have to click on flash videos when browsing YouTube.

I have not been installing Flash at all on any of my machines. I use Chrome for YouTube, since it has a sandboxed version of Flash.

**EDIT:** Almost as soon as I hit Post on my answer I noticed that "Click to Flash has been superseded by ["Click to Plugin"](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/) which appears to do much more. I haven't tried this, but it looks like the only choice for Safari 5.1 and later.

Comment: I didn't realize Chrome had its own embedded version of Flash. Uninstalling Flash and using Chrome for YouTube seems to be the most suitable solution. Thanks.

Comment: I would have suggested that as a solution, but you seemed to insist on Safari. I added that comment as an after thought. Glad you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, try this Safari Extension called YouTube5. http://www.verticalforest.com/youtube5-extension/

I've had Flash uninstalled from my Macs ever since I found this extension. If a certain site requires Flash, I'd simply use Chrome.